# PHP MySql query to delete rows doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have this php script:

```
foreach (get_all_topics () as $topic_id => $topic_info) {
   $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM marks 
                           WHERE user_id = $user_id 
                            AND topic_id = $topic_id", $db);
    echo "DELETE FROM marks 
           WHERE user_id = $user_id 
             AND topic_id = $topic_id : " . mysql_error() . " : " . mysql_affected_rows();
}
```

I have set a valid `$user_id` and `get_all_topics()` gives valid topic info as printed by `echo`. However it always returns `false` and I have a data with `user_id = 1 AND topic_id = 1` (and it also gets deleted if I copy and paste `echo`ed string in interactive mysql prompt - so no spelling mistakes!).

**NOTE:** Other functions that Insert or Update the table works just fine. I'm learning php - mysql and this is the first time I'm deleting something from database. Can anyone please suggest what is the issue with this script? Or can there be any permissions problem with this?

Comment: The first step would be to debug the queries: Echo them and try to run them manually in the database frontend and see what happens

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say ?

Comment: the SQL query looks fine, so I'd investigate elsewhere. Are you sure your get_all_topics() returns a correct array? You can try print_r(get_all_topic()); just to be sure...

Comment: what's in get_all_topics()? also, should the space between the name and parentheses be there?

Comment: @Pekka: That's what i've said in code. I'm `echo`ing everything. But loop executes just once! @codaddict, @aLostMonkey: musql_error() doesnot return anything! @Damien: Yes, 'coz what is echoed is what i want to query. ie. query builds up correctly. P.S. Just checked with print_r()

Comment: just give us the function and an SQL dump so that we can try it on our own, without the full information it is impossible to debug for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting single quotes around $user_id and $topic_id so your code will be

```
mysql_query( "DELETE FROM marks WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND topic_id='$topic_id'", $db );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The `user_id` and `topic_id` both are integers. Moreover, if I copy and paste the echoed output something like : `DELETE FROM marks WHERE user_id=1 AND topic_id=1` it works perfectly fine. But still, i'll try ur solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete all these rows once using in (id1, id2, id3)
2. You have not specified database in query (may be you have selected database before) - use `databasename`.`tablename`.
3. It depend's what your mysql_error returned since false means that there is an error.
4. May be errors somehow suspended so look in error logs.

[PHP Mysql Query Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I've selected the database earlier in the code and other queries like SELECT and UPDATE works just fine. In `echo`, both `mysql_error()` and `mysql_affected_rows()` doesn't return anything. Also the loop executes only once. Really frustrated! Will try to delete required rows in one shot using `in (id1, id2, ...)` but i thing there's no reason why they can't be deleted separately.

Comment: Please, give me sql query exactly. I'll try to help that way.

Comment: For debugging purposes try to use var_dump() since it's also prints type of variable which is very helpful.

Comment: Deleting using one statement will save you resources. Separate deletes will instantiate separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

I like to build a query string:

```
$myQuery = "DELETE FROM marks WHERE user_id= " . $user_id . "AND topic_id=" . $topic_id;
mysql_query($myQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. But I've already tried that (with a space between `"` and `AND`) But no luck :(

Answer (score -1):

The OP wrote:

> I've changed the code above to
>
> ```
> $all_topics = get_all_topics();
>
> foreach ($all_topics as $topic_id => $topic_info) {
>    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM marks 
>                            WHERE user_id = $user_id 
>                             AND topic_id = $topic_id", $db);
>     echo "DELETE FROM marks 
>            WHERE user_id = $user_id 
>              AND topic_id = $topic_id : " . mysql_error() . " : " . mysql_affected_rows();
> }
> ```
>
> and it worked! Anyone having similar problem can try assigning return value to some temp variable and then use that in the foreach loop. Don't know why it works.

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)